# htaccess redirect all users to maintenance page except my IP

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have been reading other questions here and followed indications and it seems that all works except for the params included in the URL.

Here is the .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^blog/([^/\.]+)/?$ /blog/index.php?u=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^90\.68\.245\.132
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/maintenance.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://thedomain/maintenance.php/$1 [R=302,L]
```

All Ip's except the mine one are redirected to the maintenance page.

With my IP. I can enter and open all pages but there's a problem with the params.

What's wrong?

Comment: @Chris It does not work for me. I saw such post. The URL's like domain.com/blog/post-1, the param is not seen

Comment: Add `RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^90\.68\.245\.132` line before `RewriteRule ^blog...`

Comment: What problem with what params? Please be more precise.